# Python code freezes(continuously running not showing any error) at imaplib.starttls() while connecting to outlook imap

Tags: python, python-3.x, imap, imaplib, msal

I am using below code to connect outlook.

```py
import imaplib
import msal
#Below code try to connect the Azure Cloud and get the access token and authenticate the outlook email
conf = {
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", #AppID
    "scope": ['https://outlook.office365.com/.default'],
    "secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", #Key-Value
    #"secret-id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", #Key-ID
}

def generate_auth_string(user, token):
    return f"user={user}\x01auth=Bearer {token}\x01\x01"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(conf['client_id'], authority=conf['authority'],
                                                client_credential=conf['secret'])

    result = app.acquire_token_silent(conf['scope'], account=None)

    if not result:
        print("No suitable token in cache.  Get new one.")
        result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=conf['scope'])

    if "access_token" in result:
        #print(result['token_type'])
        token_dict=result
        token=token_dict['access_token']
        #pprint.pprint(result)
    else:
        print(result.get("error"))
        print(result.get("error_description"))
        print(result.get("correlation_id"))



    imap = imaplib.IMAP4('outlook.office365.com')
    print('test')
    imap.starttls()
    print('test2')
    imap.authenticate("XOAUTH2", lambda x: generate_auth_string("xxxx@xxxx.com", result['access_token']).encode("utf-8"))
    imap.select('inbox')


    status, messages = imap.select("INBOX",readonly=False)
    # number of top emails to fetch
    N = 3
    # total number of emails
    messages1 = int(messages[0])
    print(messages1)
```

It was working fine till yesterday. Suddenly from today it is not working.
Output is showing till only test and it is continuously running at imap.starttls() without showing any error or output.

Could you please help where code went wrong.

Comment: Try adding `IMAP4.debug = 4` see if that shows debug output.

Comment: added imap.debug =4 to the code. I am seeing following output 5:01.69 > b'LCGE1 STARTTLS'

Comment: Try using IMAP4_SSL class on port 993 (TLS always, rather than upgrade via STARTTLS) and see if it helps.  It is possible MS broke the command temporarily, but it’s unlikely that the full TLS would fail.

Comment: Thanks Max... switching to imaplib.imap4_ssl resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue just now. Fixed by switching to imap = imaplib.imap4_ssl(outlook.office365.com) and removing the imap.starttls() bit. For some reason the server on port 143 now hangs when you send starttls